Positioning the wxFrame object
Using the very simple wxFrame example form the official wxWidgets site I'd like to set the created window position jut to the very upper left screen corner
so I've added the simple frame->SetPosition(wxPoint(0, 0)) line. Unfortunately for some bizarre reason there is some little, but UNWANTED "margin" from the left side as shown on the enter image description here. What is that and how to get rig of that gap to position the window precisely as expected?

at which point you call SetPosition()? Also - I presume you are using Windows with wx 3.2.5? Is you screen HighDPI?

@Igor Yes, sorry I'm using Win with wx 3.2.5, Y're right:-) I'm calling SetPosition in the MyApp::OnInit after instantiating the MyFrame class.

It is the border of the window.  Transparent on Win10+.  Move the mouse cursor there to see this, note how the cursor changes to allow dragging the edges.

As a code supplement to VZ. 's answer.
Use DwmGetWindowAttribute to get the BOUNDS and subtract WindowRect
#include<dwmapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"Dwmapi.lib")

.
bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame* frame = new MyFrame();
    frame->Show(true);
    HWND hwnd = frame->GetHWND();
    RECT extendedFrameBounds = { 0 };
    HRESULT hr = DwmGetWindowAttribute(hwnd, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, &extendedFrameBounds, sizeof(extendedFrameBounds));

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {

        RECT windowRect;
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &windowRect);


        int offsetX = extendedFrameBounds.left - windowRect.left;
        int offsetY = extendedFrameBounds.top - windowRect.top;

        frame->SetPosition(wxPoint (-offsetX, -offsetY));
       
    }
    return true;
}


This is a Windows, not wxWidgets, thing: modern version of Windows reserve some space inside the "window rectangle", for whatever reason. You may change this using DWM-specific functions, but this would make your window appear slightly differently from the default.
